# How to version using copy commands in python

Tags: python, version-control

What I am trying do is copy a file or directory from 'src' to 'dst', however, if the file that is being copied is in the 'dst' location I don't want the operation to overwrite the existing file. Can this be done directly with shutil or should I just check the 'dst' directory for the 'src' and if it exist prompt the user to rename the file they are copying? Basically, I want to create a simple 'versioning' system using python.

Comment: so the files have the same name but different contents?

Comment: Yes. I have it working right now, checking if the file/directory exist and if so the user must change the name. I was curious though, if there was a good way to simplify the code using shutil since i'm using the copy commands it provides.

Comment: you could add a predetermined suffix that you let the user choose for duplicate files at the start to avoid having to ask the user each time you encounter a file with the same name but there is also a slight chance you could still encounter dups even using that method.

Comment: Could I use a delimiter such as the period that would come before the extension, add the suffix (n_v2, n_v3 and so on), then rebuild the string. If so, how would you start from the end of the string vs the beginning?

Comment: just rsplit the filename on `.` the add what you want and use "".join() to rejoin the new string

Comment: Would this cause issues though if the string had multiple periods, such as padding for frame sequences? An example would be file.####.ext.

Comment: `your_string.rsplit(".",1)` will split on the last `.` only which will be the extension, the 1 specifies the max split

Comment: no worries, if you get stuck I will give you an example

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with. It's pretty rough. If anyone has suggestions on how to slim the code let me know.

```
import os
import shutil

srcCheck = 'n'
dstCheck = 'n'

dstDirVer = 2
dstFileVer = 2

dirExitVar = False
fileExitVar = False

src = input('Directory or file to be commited: \n')
print('Is this directory or file correct? > ' + src)

srcCheck = input('(y/n) > ')

while srcCheck != 'y':
    src = input('Directory or file to be commited: \n')
    print('Is this directory or file correct? > ' + src)
    srcCheck = input('(y/n) > ')

while dstCheck != 'y':
    dst = input('Where to commit: \n')
    print('Is this directory or file correct? > ' + dst)
    dstCheck = input('(y/n) > ')

srcIsDir = os.path.isdir(src)
dstDirExist = os.path.isdir(dst)
dstFileExist = os.path.isfile(dst)

while dstDirExist == True:

    while dirExitVar == False:

        try:
            dstPrevDir, dstDirVer = dst.rsplit("v",1)

        except ValueError:
            dst = dst + '_v' + str(dstDirVer)

        dirExitVar = True

    dstPrevDir, dstDirVer = dst.rsplit("v",1)
    dstDirVer = int(dstDirVer) + 1
    dst = dstPrevDir + 'v' + str(dstDirVer)
    dstDirExist = os.path.isdir(dst)


while dstFileExist == True:

    dstPrevFile, dstExt = dst.rsplit(".",1)

    while fileExitVar == False:

        try:
            dstPrevFileRoot, dstFileVer = dstPrevFile.rsplit("v",1)

        except ValueError:
            dstPrevFile = dstPrevFile + '_v' + str(dstFileVer)

        fileExitVar = True

    dstPrevFileRoot, dstFileVer = dstPrevFile.rsplit("v",1)
    dst = dstPrevFileRoot + 'v' + str(dstFileVer) + '.' + dstExt
    dstFileVer = int(dstFileVer) + 1
    dstFileExist = os.path.isfile(dst)


if srcIsDir == True:
    shutil.copytree(src, dst)
if srcIsDir == False:
    shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
```